# Issue in assigning dynamically created cart rule to the cart after clicking add to cart button

Tags: hook, prestashop

I am using prestashop 1.5.6.0. When user clicks on add to cart button, I am creating cart rule and assigning it to cart, if I click on "Cart" link at the top right, I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function getProducts() on a non-object in /classes/CartRule.php on line 565 for the first time when cart is empty. But if cart is not empty then I am not getting error.

For assigning cart rule to shopping cart, i had used below code:

```
public function hookActionCartSave($params){
    $code = $this->context->cookie->__get('token');

    if (($cartRule = new CartRule(CartRule::getIdByCode($code))) && Validate::isLoadedObject($cartRule)) {
        if ($error = $cartRule->checkValidity($this->context, false, true)) {
            $this->errors[] = $error;
        } else {
            $this->context->cart->addCartRule($cartRule->id);
       }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help in fixing this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why you do that? If you don't set a code to a cart rule, it will be added to your cart automatically...

And for your error, the problem is that your cart isn't filled in your context when the hook is fired. So if you really need to do it that way, you will have to create your own hook, placed in the ParentOrderController, in the function "initContent", this is where cart rule are checked and added.

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that a valid `Cart` object exists in the `Context` object even though it may not. It won't when this function is called during the initial cart creation process, for example.

The rule will be meaningless on an empty cart anyway.

Just add:

```
if (!isset($this->context->cart) || !$this->context->cart || !$this->context->cart->nbProducts())
    return;
```

As the first line of your hook function and that should do the trick. I'm assuming that otherwise your cart rule logic functions correctly (e.g. when the cart contains products).

EDIT: Just to clarify further. `$cartRule->checkValidity($this->context, false, true)` depends on a `Cart` object in the `Context` and may return `null` or `false` if one isn't set.